# Invite twitter user to private twitter account

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I would like to invite users who signed up for a newsletter to follow my private twitter account by sending them an e-mail invitation to do so? Haven't found anything inside the https://developer.twitter.com/ docs.

Where I can find some more information or docs about this?

I have searched SO, Google, but without any success.

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/web/follow-button // Be aware though that this will likely not work directly _inside_ an e-mail - this needs some JS code to be embedded, and JS almost always gets filtered out of e-mails completely.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Follow web intent documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/web/follow-button/web-intent), you can add a link in your email pointing to https://twitter.com/intent/follow?screen_name=YOURTWITTERACCOUNT

Comment: In that case the user would send you a request to follow (I think) - I haven’t tried it, to be fair.